# How to get website automatically added into Chrome's my list of other search engines?

Tags: google-chrome, automation, search-engines

So I'm a developer and on Stack Overflow but don't know if this question exactly qualifies to be over there.  Kind of depends on if the answer if one requires code so I'm asking here instead.

Today I found out about Chrome's automatic adding of search engines for certain sites you visit feature; so I have sites like StackOverflow, php.net, CNN, Craigslist, etc.. that allows me to search those sites by typing the address first followed by a tab or space and the keyword(s) to search for.

I'm guessing the browser auto detects search forms to add them into Chrome's list but is there a certain criteria to get it to pick up your search form?  I have some sites I've developed that I'd like if chrome picked up the search feature for so users of my site can use that functionality if they use chrome.

I've noticed most of the sites I have listed currently are pretty big known mainstream sites but there's a couple that are not.  So does Chrome's search auto add only work on more popular sites, or do these sites have something configured or setup that's telling Chrome this is our search form and the variable that should be used to search with and so forth?

Thanks; I can move this question to Stack if it better fits there or somewhere else...

Answer (score 5):

So I found the answer from some help in an IRC chat.

The answer is you can have your site automatically added into Chromes search engine list using the OpenSearch description document of the OpenSearch spec.

I also found out that apparently multiple browsers support the OpenSearch spec and that its been around for some time now... so that was quite interesting to find.

Some helpful links:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSearch

http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/1.1

http://blog.unto.net/add-opensearch-to-your-site-in-five-minutes.html